# Formik from being Posted successfully only problem is the part of from that has files is being Posted as empty array

Tags: typescript, forms, post, next.js, formik

im trying to create a form using Formik, typescript and next js, and the form has multiple text input and has an file input of type jpeg/png, the Form is being Posted successfully to my test server ( using Json server) and i can see my data, the only problem is the images file data is being saved as an array of empty objects i have no clue why its doing that
here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Field, Form, Formik, validateYupSchema } from "formik";
import { validationSchema } from "@/schemas/ticketSchema";
import { TicketsProps } from "@/types/tickets";
import PreviewImage from "./previewImage";
import { addNewTickets } from "@/public/api/api";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const AddTicketForm: React.FC<TicketsProps> = ({
  clientList,
  brandList,
  offenseList,
}) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        client: "",
        regNumber: "",
        brand: "",
        date: "",
        time: "",
        offense: "",
        description: "",
        images: [],
      }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        const formData = new FormData();

        resetForm();
        const data = await addNewTickets({
          id: uuidv4(),
          client: values.client,
          brand: values.brand,
          regNumber: values.regNumber,
          date: values.date,
          time: values.time,
          offense: values.offense,
          description: values.description,
          images: formData,
        });
        console.log("Data", data);
        console.log(formData);
      }}
    >
      {(props) => (
        <Form className="flex flex-col items-center font-primary">
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="client">
            Client
          </label>
          <Field className={"w-[300px]"} id="client" as="select" name="client">
            <option value={"Select Client"}>Please select a client</option>

            {clientList.map((client) => (
              <option key={client.id}>{client.name}</option>
            ))}
          </Field>
          {props.touched.client && props.errors.client && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">Please select a client</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="regNumber">
            {props.errors.client}
          </label>
          <Field
            className={"w-[300px]"}
            id="regNumber"
            name="regNumber"
            type="text"
          ></Field>
          {props.touched.regNumber && props.errors.regNumber && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.regNumber}</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="brand">
            Brand
          </label>
          <Field className={"w-[300px]"} id="brand" as="select" name="brand">
            <option value={"Select brand"}>Please select a brand</option>

            {brandList.map((brand) => (
              <option key={brand.id} value={brand.name}>
                {brand.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
          {props.touched.brand && props.errors.brand && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.brand}</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="offense">
            Offense
          </label>
          <Field
            className={"w-[300px]"}
            id="offense"
            as="select"
            name="offense"
          >
            <option value={"Select offense"}>Please select an offense</option>

            {offenseList.map((offense) => (
              <option key={offense.id} value={offense.name}>
                {offense.name} {offense.price}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
          {props.touched.offense && props.errors.offense && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.offense}</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="date">
            Date
          </label>
          <Field
            id="date"
            name="date"
            type="date"
            className="w-[300px]"
          ></Field>
          {props.touched.date && props.errors.date && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.date}</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px]" htmlFor="time">
            Time
          </label>
          <Field
            id="time"
            name="time"
            type="time"
            className="w-[300px]"
          ></Field>
          {props.touched.time && props.errors.time && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.time}</p>
          )}
          <label className="mt-[20px] font-primary" htmlFor="description">
            Description(Optional)
          </label>
          <Field
            id="description"
            name="description"
            rows="8"
            as="textarea"
            className="w-[300px] font-primary"
          ></Field>
          <label className="mt-[20px] font-primary" htmlFor="images">
            <h1 className="font-primary text-[25px] font-bold text-center">
              Images{" "}
            </h1>
            <div className="font-primary text-[25px] font-bold text-white text-center cursor-pointer hover:text-black hover:bg-white hover:border-[1px] hover:border-black bg-black px-[50px] rounded-[10%]">
              +
            </div>
          </label>
          <input
            id="images"
            name="images"
            hidden
            type="file"
            className="w-[300px] font-primary"
            accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
            multiple={true}
            onChange={(e: any) => {
              if (
                props.values.images.length + e.currentTarget.files.length <=
                10
              ) {
                props.setFieldValue(
                  "images",
                  props.values.images.concat(Array.from(e.currentTarget.files))
                );
              } else {
                props.setFieldError("images", "Max number of images is 10");
              }
            }}
          ></input>
          {props.touched.images && props.errors.images && (
            <p className="text-start text-red-500">{props.errors.images}</p>
          )}
          {props.values.images.length > 0 && (
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap mt-[50px] w-[600px] justify-center items-center gap-[30px] ">
              {props.values.images.map((file, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="flex items-center relative overflow-[hiden]  h-[150px]"
                >
                  <PreviewImage file={file}></PreviewImage>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => {
                      props.values.images.splice(index, 1);
                    }}
                    className="absolute top-0 right-0 text-[20px] text-red-500 font-bold bg-white px-[5px] py-[5px]"
                  >
                    X
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}

          <button
            type="submit"
            className="rounded-[10%] font-primary text-white bg-black px-[30px] hover:scale-[1.05] hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white hover:border-[2px] hover:border-black py-[10px] mt-[20px]"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default AddTicketForm;
```

and here is my api of adding new data im using

```
export const addNewTickets = async (ticket: ITickets): Promise<ITickets> => {
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/tickets`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(ticket),
  });
  const updatedToDo = await res.json();
  return updatedToDo;
};
```

and this is my ITicket interface

```
export interface ITickets {
  id: string;
  client: string;
  brand: string;
  regNumber: string;
  date: string;
  time: string;
  offense: string;
  description: string;
  images: any;
}
```

i tried using changing multipart/form-data instead of application/json in my headers, and tried completely removing it but that way i get only a random object with a random id property in the Posted object

i also tried to use form data and formdata.append but didnt really know how to use it since all the guides show forms with just the file input while i have other inputs with my file input